# Including an image in a list

Tags: html, css, html-lists

I'm struggling to get an image in a list. When I do the following:

```
<ul>
 <li><img src="image.jpg"></li>
</ul>
```

An image icon appears (like an error) and the image doesn't show. Is there anyway to display the image?

Comment: That is correct, check your path is right. Use the developers tools F12 to find what the error is.

Comment: There's no errors showing up

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using `<img src="..."/>` you can choose two path types.

**Local Filesystem**

You can select an image to use from the local filesystem. Can be either definite path (`C:/Users/...`) or relative to the current folder.
In your example, you are looking for a file named `image.jpg` in the **current folder** which most likely does not exist.

Please note that the file location must be relative to the location of the HTML file.

**Remote Image Location**

You can insert a link to a remotely hosted image, something like `http://your-favorite-image-hosting.com/someimage.jpg`.

Comment: @frog1944 If you use `<img src="https://www.google.co.il/images/nav_logo242_hr.png"/>` does it work? If not, try outside of the <ul> tag and tell me the result.

Answer (score 1):

It should work. Like what other people have been saying, double check your URL.

Here's an example that works:

```
<ul>
 <li><img src="http://images.clipartpanda.com/smiley-face-clip-art-niXoRMbiB.png"></li>
 <li>Second item in list</li>
 <li>Third item in list</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Thank you, it was my url that was the issue

Comment: @frog1944 Awesome, glad you fixed it!

Answer (score 0):

Your code (as it is now) is looking for image.jpg in the CURRENT folder (meaning the same folder where the page of your code is).
It seems that your image must be in a different folder as the page of your code.

As a test, leave your code as is and make sure the image.jpg is in the same folder as the page of your code (if not, place it there). If you still can't see your image then the name or your image might be wrong (check again the name and extension of your image file).